# Finding the number of times a name is in a string

Tags: function, count, return

string = "Hamza flew his kite today. But Hamza forgot to play basketball"

def count_name():
count = 0
for sub_str in string:
if sub_str == "Hamza":
count += 1
return count

print(count_name())

My goal here was to find the number of times the name "Hamza", appears in the string.
But it keeps returning 0, instead of 2.

I tried setting the variable count = 0, so it can count how many times the name "Hamza" appears in the string.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: What you wrote is better described by another variable name `for character in string`.  Most languages (you didn't tag yours) treat String as an array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

The countName function takes a string as an argument and returns the number of times "Hamza" appears in it. Here is one way to count the number of times "Hamza" appears in a given string:

```js
function countName(str) {
  let count = 0;
  let index = str.indexOf("Hamza");

  while (index != -1) {
    count++;
    index = str.indexOf("Hamza", index + 1);
  }

  return count;
}

let string = "Hamza flew his kite today. But Hamza forgot to play basketball";
let count = countName(string);
console.log(count);  // Output: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

when you do `for sub_str in string:` you are looking at one letter a time (not one word at a time). You are checking...

```
'H'=='Hamza' which returns False
'a'=='Hamza' which returns False
'm'=='Hamza' which returns False...
```

that is why your count will never increase.
Luckily for you python has built in methods to make your life easy.

Try `string.count('Hamza')`